# What does stanton mean physically?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

In heat transfer, we come across Stanton number which is the ratio of heat transferred into a fluid to the thermal capacity of the fluid. But what does this physically mean and its importance in engineering applications?

Comment: This should be a good read for you : http://facstaff.cbu.edu/rprice/lectures/mtcoeff.html

Comment: i'm not good at thermodynamics but sometimes dimensionless numbers make the calculations convenient. Sometimes some quantities have no physical meaning, like reactive power in power engineering.

Comment: Reactive power has a physical meaning when you get the bill....

Comment: @SolarMike we spend an awful amount of time back in college to convince ourselves what does it really mean, but your argument is the most convincing and hilarious one up to this moment.

Answer (score 1):

The physical mean of St No. How much energy the fluid can adhere. More the heat capacity more the energy accumulated by the fluid. The significance can be very well understood by the refrigerants quality criteria in the HVAC systems.